# Obtener empleados que aún no han registrado a nómina

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día. Supongamos que tengo esta info:

```
Empleados:
ID----NOMBRE
1-----JUAN
2-----PABLO

NominaEmpleados
ID----IDEmpleado
1-----2
```

Estoy intentando hacer algún query que me devuelva el empleado que aún no está en la tabla NominaEmpleados. ¿Cómo puedo obtener este dato?

Algo así tengo en mente, pero no hace lo que necesito:

```
select e.* from empleados e, Nominas_Empleados ne   where ne.Id_Nomina=1 and e.Id not in(ne.Id_Empleado)
```

Comment: Por favor, aprende a usar `JOIN` existe desde hace mucho tiempo y es parte de una sintaxis más completa y flexible.

Comment: era sólo una idea, sé que las tablas, tal cual como puse el query, no es lo correcto, pero la observación se agradece hermano :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ibas por semi buen camino, con un `NOT IN` tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT *
FROM Empleados e
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT idEmpleado FROM NominaEmpleados)
;
```

Ahora bien, si en la tabla `NominaEmpleados` hubiera algún `NULL`, tendrías resultados inesperados. Por lo mismo, te recomiendo usar `NOT EXISTS` en estos casos:

```
SELECT *
FROM Empleados e
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM NominaEmpleados
                 WHERE idEmpleado = e.id)
;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from Empleados
where idEmpleado not in
(select idEmpleado 
 from NominaEmpleados)
```

Esta consulta devuelve todos los empleados cuyo **id** no se encuentra en la subconsulta que analiza las nóminas de los empleados.